# About <unistd.h> header file

Tags: c++, c

I have the host name of my machine. I use the `gethostname()` function from the `<unistd.h>` header file. I downloaded `<unistd.h>` from [here](http://www.koders.com/) but when I'm trying to compile it, the compiler reports the following error:

```
"Cannot open include file: 'sys/cdefs.h': No such file or directory".
```

What's the problem?

Comment: are you trying this code in windows??\

Comment: You can't just download a header file from a random website and expect it to work. Even if it compiled you'd get a linker error.

Comment: @interjay heaader files are mostly unrelated to linker errors. In the wast majority of the cases, foreign headers simply don't compile.

Comment: @H2CO3: If you include a header file when you don't have its related implementation file or library you'll get a linker error.

Comment: @interjay that's true, but now it's not the case.

Comment: @H2CO3: Which is why I said "even if it compiled"...

Answer (score 12):

Presumably, you're using Windows or some other non-POSIX platform; otherwise, `<unistd.h>` should already be available.

In that case, you can't simply download and include random Unix headers and expect them to work; you'll need to either use the Windows version (in this case, I think [`<Winsock2.h>` gives that function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738527%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)), or use a Unix-like environment such as [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/).